# PHP: Undefined index even after checking IsSet

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, undefined-index

I have read the other questions, none have answered nor helped me.

Here is my issue, I have an object/array which contains a property which is also an object/array.

I have successfully accessed similar properties before via:

```
$variable[propertyObject][property]
```

However, I have been receiving the error **Notice: Undefined index** lately.

Here is the code:

```
$extensionData = $data['Data'];
echo '<p>' . isset($extensionData['Calories']) ? $extensionData['Calories'] : '' . '</p>';
```

However, that still throws the same error. Even when I check:

`isset($extensionData['Calories'])`, it always resolves to 1/True which means the property should exist, so how can the index be undefined?

And when I do a var_dump or print_r of `$extensionData`, this is what I get:

```
Array
(
    [Calories] => 295
    [WebDesktopImage] => https://clutch-asset-management.s3.amazonaws.com/elevation-burger/IMG_0760-Edit.jpg
    [WebMobileImage] => https://clutch-asset-management.s3.amazonaws.com/elevation-burger/IMG_0760-Edit.jpg
    [WebDescription] => BLT image
)
```

Comment: Put `(parentheses)` around your ternary operation. It's probably messing things around.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thanks but that didn't work, worst part is that it passes isset but then suddenly says it's an undefined index

Comment: Is this in a loop? Try writing `isset($extensionData['Calories']) var_dump($extensionData['Calories']);` before the `echo` statement.

Comment: Instead of trying it inline, I declared a variable at the beginning of the function and that somehow resolved it, very weird.

Comment: @AnimaSola Please see my answer below

Comment: For future reference, [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) should help. You already have some answers that show it, but basically it's because `.` has higher precedence than `?:`.

Answer (score 12):

The ternary expression:

```
isset($extensionData['Calories']) ? $extensionData['Calories'] : ''
```

is OK when used stand-alone like this:

```
echo isset($extensionData['Calories']) ? $extensionData['Calories'] : '';

$tmp_var = isset($extensionData['Calories']) ? $extensionData['Calories'] : '';

return isset($extensionData['Calories']) ? $extensionData['Calories'] : '';
```

because it is equivalent to the expected:

```
if(isset($extensionData['Calories']))
{
    // use $extensionData['Calories']
}
else
{
    // use empty string ''
}
```

but, when used in string concatenation then you need parenthesis in order to confine the scope of the comparison so that the leading string is not part of the comparison

```
echo '<p>' . (isset($extensionData['Calories']) ? $extensionData['Calories'] : '') . '</p>';
```

---

Doing (wrong way):

```
echo '<p>' . isset($extensionData['Calories']) ? $extensionData['Calories'] : '' . '</p>';
```

is equivalent to

```
if('<p>' . isset($extensionData['Calories'])) // The leading string is used in the comparison and the result of isset() (boolean) is appended to the string so 100% of the time this example will be true because of how loose comparisons work
{
    echo $extensionData['Calories']; // Produces Undefined index error
}
else
{
    echo '' . '</p>';
}
```

---

In conclusion:

When in doubt, add parenthesis.

When not in doubt, add parenthesis anyways because the code will be more legible when you have to re-visit it in 6 months. Most text editors have parenthesis and bracket match highlighting so adding parenthesis is a very beneficial way to declare and later see the operation's intended behavior.

See [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) if you come across someone's cryptic code and need help figuring out what on Earth they were thinking and/or failed to consider.

Comment: You are a life saver, how come this answer did not get many upvotes ?

Comment: @KhanShahrukh I'm glad you found this useful. As for the upvotes, Stack Overflow works in mysterious ways :-p

Answer (score 1):

The following code will evaluate to True and thus your isset() query is negated:

```
echo '<p>' . isset($extensionData['Calories'])
```

This will return True because the string '<p>' is true.

Try this:

```
echo '<p>' . ( isset($extensionData['Calories']) ? $extensionData['Calories'] : '' ) . '</p>';
```

Answer (score 1):

The problems is in your ternary operation. Your `isset()` with ternary operator is a bitty messy, you're not defining the scope when concatenating with a string. You need to add parenthesis to you ternary operation and isolate the string from the operation. The `if`statement for your code is the same as

```
if('<p>'. isset($extensionData['Calorie']))
{
   echo $extensionData[´Calorie´];
}
else 
{
  echo ''.'</p>';
}
```

I reccomend you to put it in a variable in order to organize your code better

```
$extensionData = $data['Data'];
$varCalorie = (isset($extensionData['Calories']) ? $extensionData['Calories'] : ''); 
echo '<p>'. $varCalorie . '<p/>';
```

The above would be identical to

```
if (isset($extensionData['Calories'])) {
    $varCalorie = $extensionData['Calories'];
    echo '<p>'. $varCalorie . '<p/>'; 
} else {
    $varCalorie = '';
    echo '<p>'. $varCalorie . '<p/>'; 
}
```

You can also do

```
echo isset($extensionData['Calories']) ? $extensionData['Calories'] : '';
return isset($extensionData['Calories']) ? $extensionData['Calories'] : '';
```